# div not appending properly in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to insert the VLC player in the div i.e. `mainstream_container1`

It is inserting into that particular div but not in a proper manner.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fb99LL3z/9/)

I am not able to figure out where it is going wrong.
Please somebody help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's what you want, but you can :

- set a fixed height (400px for example) to the `tbody` of `table
  table-striped table-rounded table-condensed table-subtable`
- change the position of the `.videoOverlay` to `absolute`.

[See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/fb99LL3z/11/)

Comment: thanks :) it worked for me.